# -presentViewController:animated:completion:  iOS6

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Вместо методов

```
-presentModalViewController  
-dismissModalViewController
```

в последнем икскоде предлагается использовать для этой цели новый метод -`presentViewController:animated:completion:`, старые депрекейчены, возможности использовать их нет. Каким образом в таком случае организовывается dismiss модального контоллера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так ведь есть метод `– dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`
Он же не deprecated.

Comment: Так это и есть парный метод -presentViewController:animated:completion: ?

Comment: Ну да, если есть present метод, то должен быть и dismiss метод. У `UINavigationController` вместо этих методов есть push и pop.

Comment: Благодарю Вас!